# Excel Formula that Match the Year and Quarter then Paste the Result

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have been using a Microsoft Excel formula that matches the `Year` and `Quarter` in `Sheet1` then copies the required cell value and then paste that value into `Sheet2 COl"B"`.

My formula is not dynamic it just works for year `2020` not for further years available in Sheet1 that are `2021` and `2020`

I have tried to create something that works for my but could not. I have attached a Google Sheet please have look into it.

Your help will be highly appreciated.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VgFn2Rpw3PAG_pBg1-YWfTexGuHHzzqiGBiUQDbpwLE/edit#gid=758402044

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `C14` of Sheet2 try:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,LOOKUP(2,1/((Sheet1!B$2:B$15=C$1+INT(COUNT(C$13:C13)/4))*(Sheet1!C$2:C$15=MOD(COUNT(C$13:C13),4)+1)),Sheet1!E$2:E$15),"")
```

Comment: There is problem that when i remove the data from Sheet1 except 2020 it does not work and gives #N/A @JvdV it should give 2020 result in Sheet except others

Comment: Works for me. What could have happened is that you deleted rows and that messed up the column B references. If you don't have too many calculations you can use a whole column reference instead of `B2:B15` use `B:B`

Comment: Oooh yes that was the issue Thank you now its working accurate.

Comment: can you please tell me one more thing when i remove or add any data in Sheet1 why it is not calculate automatically @JvdV

Comment: Look at the picture i have added it just updated the 71 not updated other values https://ibb.co/n8XnyZp can we convert this thing in VBA because the formula is not working smoothly

Comment: @Learning, could be several issues: Either you haven't dragged the formula down *or* you havent got the automatic calculations on the "Formula" tab.

Comment: I did both i do not know what is the issue here i attached tow pictures Sheet1 have Data But Sheet2 is not giving proper answer. https://ibb.co/55pCCf3
https://ibb.co/SQPxZzv @JvdV

Comment: @Learning, it's hard to troubleshoot what exactly you are doing here. I don't have my Excel sheet nomore to test it either. The answer is based on the 4 quarters per year being present, it worked on your sample data you gave before. Try to troubleshoot this yourself by evaluating step by step what the formula does using the "Evaluate Formula" function.

Comment: Ok l will try it at my end otherwise if does not resolve will post new question ?

Comment: @Learning, that is up to you but I'm not going back and fourth on questions with changing data and requirements to be honest. I hope you can work it out.